# How can i rotate an image on matlab without getting the black background

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Checking https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html i can use imrotate but i will get an image with a black background like this:

[image]

and i want an image more like this:

[image]

basically, i don't want to add any black or white pixels or any pixels at all i just want my image to rotate without any additional background.

Kindly note that when i display the second image on matlab it also shows with black background and a bunch of 0 pixels

Comment: I think that you are confusing the image itself and the window (or frame) in which it is displayed.  Your second image looks to me like it has white pixels padding it to fit into a rectangular frame for display, as opposed to the black ones in your first image.  But your question seems to suggest that's not what you want.  Do you mean you want some kind of image file which stores one pixel for the first line, 3 for the second line, 5, for the 3rd, *etc* ?  Good luck finding that.

Comment: Make the black area (background) transparent ... that's the only way. As Mark just explained, the _image data_ will always be a **rectangular area**, it's your job to display (or not) each pixel the way you want.

Comment: It if is the *displayed* image you want to rotate, display it as usual, get the handle to the `image` graphics object, then call [`rotate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rotate.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use

J = imrotate(I,angle,method,'loose')

To save in J the full image (containing the 0 pixels at the border).
Then using rgb2ind (https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) or bwconncomp (https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) you can identify the connected components which enclose the image (there should be 4): in this way you can change the color of those pixels in white
To avoid having 4 components you could firstly add one black rectangle yourself, so that the image J will be completely enclosed by black pixels